# Invalid signature error al verificar JsonWebToken

Tags: nodejs, express, rest, jwt, zod

Estoy desarrollando una api REST con TypeScript, express y Zod,al momento de crear una nueva session, recibir los acces y refresh tokens, al momento de hacer un GET a las sessiones activas actuales recibo el error: `Invalid signature` en la siguiente función para verificar el token:

```
export function verifyJwt(token:string) {

    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, publicKey);
        
        return {
            valid: true,
            expired: false,
            decoded,
        };

    }catch(err:any){
        console.log("This is the err -> ", err.message)
        return {
            valid: false,
            expired: err.message === "jwt expired",
            decoded: null,
        };
    }
}
```

La función para firmar los tokens es esta:

```
//Getting public and private key
const privateKey = config.get<string>("privateKey");
const publicKey = config.get<string>("publicKey");

export function signJwt(payload: Object, options?: jwt.SignOptions | undefined) {
    
    return jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, {
        ...(options && options),
        algorithm: "RS256"
    });
}
```

Este es el controlador para la ruta POST para crear una nueva sesion:

```
export async function createUserSessionHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {
    
    // Validate user credentials

    const user = await validatePassword(request.body);

    if(!user){
        return response.status(401).send("Invalid email or password");
    }

    // Create a session

    const session = await createSession(user._id, request.get("user-agent") || "");


    // Create access token

    const accessToken = signJwt(
        {...user, session: session._id},
        {expiresIn: config.get<string>(
            "accessTokenTtl"
        )} // 15 minutes
    );

    // Create refresh token

    const refreshToken = signJwt(
        {...user, session: session._id},
        {expiresIn: config.get<string>(
            "refreshTokenTtl"
        )} // 1 year
    );

    
    // Send refresh & access token back

    return response.send({accessToken, refreshToken});

}
```

Estas son las rutas referentes a las sessions:

```
app.post(
    "/api/sessions",
    validateResource(createSessionSchema),
    createUserSessionHandler
);

app.get('/api/sessions', requireUser , getUserSessionsHandler);
```

He hecho console.log() en ambas keys(private, public) y son correctas al momento de usarlas,
igualmente la función `verifyToken` recibe el token correctamente. Que puede causar el problema ?

Comment: Puede que no estés validando con la llave que se firmó

Comment: Mmm, logré hacerlo funcionar tomando tu sugerencia y usé la privateKey en la función para verificar token y funciona correctamente, pero me queda la duda porque con el algoritmo "RS256" las llaves deberían ser asimétricas.

Comment: Es correcto, es asimétrico. Y la llave pública se usa para firmar. La llave privada sólo la tiene el servidor para validar lo firmado.